# By convention should pg data be in a static (postgres) or versioned (postgresql@14) directory?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres v14 installed via Homebrew on MacOS Ventura.

I just ran a minor version update 14.7 - 14.8 to try an fix a missing file/ library issue.

But I've created a new issue!

I cannot run `psql`

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I now have a (different - previously this was postgres.log) active log file at `/usr/local/var/log/postgresql@14.log` with last entry

```
postgres: could not access directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@14": No such file or directory
Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
```

This `postgresql@14` directory should not exist, my pg data is in `/usr/local/var/postgres`.

Has something changed in postgres? After searching through the website and release notes I could not find anything.

What is the convention here? Should I version my data directory `mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgresql@14`, or is there a config option somewhere to retain the `postgres` directory?

Comment: What Homebrew formula did you use this [Homebrew-postgresq;](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql) or something else?

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver i'm using the official formula https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/postgresql@14#default

Comment: From what I see this is a Homebrew change: [Rename from Postgresql](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/8060df9169055ee1fb9d1d69fd149c3922e864ba) and [Directory Migration caveat](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/037fb584cc7b6dbef25fb9f001e22eef4e7ee408).

Comment: thanks @AdrianKlaver. I have moved everything into a versioned data directory, and all seems to be working correctly. Good to know that this was a Homebrew change, though not sure why I did not see / how I overlooked the warning message. Thanks all the same!!